# ARIMA model not capturing the seasonality

Tags: arima, seasonality

I am trying to forecast the leakage rate through seals. Raw data consists of measurements of data which was recorded every second for 60 minutes. The frequency here is 60. To start with I used the first 30 minutes data to find the model that could predict the next 5 minutes data.

[image: I decomposed my time series using decompose function in r and I get this image]

What does seasonality in this data mean? I believe the model found using `auto.arima` function is not capturing the seasonality.

[image: Arima (2,2,4) model not capturing seasonality]

Is seasonality in this data significant or should I remove them from the time series? If I had to include them in the model, how can I do so?

Comment: Actually, I think you have it backwards: your subject matter expertise should tell you if there should be any seasonality, and if so what it would reflect. You don't auto-fit something and then try to guess what the subject-matter-non-expert auto procedure's guess as to seasonality might mean.

Comment: Look at the labels on the vertical axes.  The "seasonal" amplitude is only a fifth of the "random" component!

Comment: @Wayne I'd like to disagree with this view. In many problems, the underlying seasonality is unclear and subject knowledge may actually misguide. In fact, often the most useful result out of an arima model is its estimate of the true seasonality.

Comment: @horaceT: I hear you, but it sounds like we have a differing definition of what "subject matter expertise", if it can be misleading. (Though admittedly "experts" that we're allowed to talk to aren't always actually experts.) Still, the bottom line for me is that we humans are way too good at making sense of any random result for me to be comfortable running automated procedures with no model or physical causes (in this case) in mind. Not to mention that ARIMA results can be physically untenable, and there are non-model alternatives to identify seasonality as well.

Comment: @Wayne Can you give an example of a non-model trick to estimate seasonal pattern?

Comment: @horaceT: No special tricks, I'm thinking basic data exploration like ACF plots, etc. When I say "identify", I'm thinking literally identify, not identify with accompanying p-value, etc. I'm trying to emphasize knowledge work as a precursor to statistics work.

Comment: @Wayne Points taken. Would be useful to have systematic ways to get that.